# WPF DataGrid SelectionUnit property overwritten by RowStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a DataGrid with the SelectionUnit property set to "FullRow". This was working as expected, however I needed to change the row background color based on some conditions and all of a sudden the SelectionUnit in execution time is being changed to "Cell". This is the XAML code of the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding order, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="dgOrders_ScrollChanged" DockPanel.Dock="Top" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  Name="dgOrders" ItemsSource="{Binding delivery_orders_list}" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="dgOrders_OnSelectionChanged" Height="450" SelectedIndex="{Binding orders_index}">

    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding has_changed}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSalmon"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="{x:Static resx:lang.order_is_printed}" Binding="{Binding is_printed}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static resx:lang.serie}" Binding="{Binding series.serie}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static resx:lang.order_number}" Binding="{Binding order_number}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static resx:lang.commensal}" Binding="{Binding commensal.contact_name}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

If I remove the DataGrid.RowStyle tag, then the SelectionUnit goes back to normal.

What could be happening?

PS: I'm using the MahApps.Metro library for the UI.

Comment: couldn't reproduce your issue.